# Neo4j : Semantic difference between "WITH DISTINCT x RETURN count (x)" and "RETURN count (distinct x)"?

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher

I have a Neo4j database where I'm trying to count the (distinct) nodes reachable by paths of length at most 10 through any relation. My question is quite simple, if you can spare the time, but it's quite specific and I'm not sure I can find this topic in the documentation.
My initial approach was this:
`MATCH path = (a)-[*1..10]-(b) WHERE a.name="blabla" RETURN count(distinct b);`
but I've been told I should use
`MATCH path = (a)-[*1..10]-(b) WHERE a.name="blabla" WITH distinct b RETURN count(b);` instead.
Is there any particular reason to use one over the other? At first glance both seem equivalent, and seem to yield the same results, but I'm wondering if they actually are.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Prefix both of your queries with `PROFILE` and compare the execution plans, this is the best way to understand what differences there might be: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/query-tuning/#how-do-i-profile-a-query

Comment: I made the test, the profile shows that the latest takes the distinct feature out of the aggregation function, but the same amount of dbhits is done. I don't believe it changes anything. I believe it's just a readability thing.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did the test too and (as a beginner still) couldn't read much of a difference, though I wasn't sure if I was missing something. Thanks for confirming :)